# v-bind in b-list-group-item not working in vue CLI-app with boootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, axios, vue-cli

i have an app made with vue-CLI including bootstrap-vue. In my App.vue i'am using axios to fetch some sample JSON-data. I generate a list with the **b-list-group-item** (bootstrap-tag) and want to bind a key in each element (**v-bind:key="result.ItemId"**). This is not working. In html no "key" is rendered.

This is the code snippet:

```
 <b-list-group >
      <b-list-group-item
        href="#"
        class="flex-column align-items-start"
        v-for="result in post"
        v-bind:key="result.ItemId"
      >
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
          <h6 class="mb-1">{{ result.ItemHeading }}</h6>
          <small>{{ result.ItemSubHeading }}</small>
        </div>

        <p class="mb-1">{{ result.ItemDetails }}</p>

      </b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>
```

This is the rendered html with no key-binding:

[image]

This is the JSON-result:

```
0: {ItemId: "10075328", ItemHeading: "news im November", ItemSubHeading: "unter news",…}
Date4Itemnew: "24.11.2019"
ItemDetails: "lorem ipsum"
ItemHeading: "news im November"
ItemId: "10075328"
ItemSubHeading: "unter news"
u_date: "1574550000"
```

I tried all possibilities to bind it. Please help.

Comment: Key is only used for Vue to proper handling of list items.

Comment: What does this mean? If i use "id" or "john" its the same problem. Can you please explain.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Vue only renders into the DOM what really needs to be there. So, there is e.g. no `v-if="true"` in the DOM, but the element is either there or not. The same with the key. It is used within Vue internally but is not rendered into the DOM. The `key` attribute is used to indicate to Vue when an element should rerender its content. When the key changes, Vue reloads that component.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. If i build an app without the vue-CLI i can e.g. add elements ( id= ...) in my list-item.  `<a id="10107333" target="_self" href="#" class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start list-group-item-action"><div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between"><h6 class="mb-1">MusterBank</h6> <small>25.01.2019</small></div>` . I need an ID or key for further use of this list-element.

Comment: Did you try bind `id` like this: `<b-list-group-item v-for="result in post" :id="result.ItemId">`?

Comment: yes, like this: `<b-list-group v-if="results">
                <b-list-group-item 
                    href="#" 
                    class="flex-column align-items-start" 
                    v-for="result in filteredList" 
                    v-bind:id="result.ItemId">`

Comment: Are you needing this only to handle the item later? If so, wouldn't something like `@click="someMethod(result.ItemId)"` work?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to loop inside the json file by value of key [ result.ItemHeading ] , After you have to bind this value inside props by same name of value  props: ["ItemHeading", "ItemSubHeading", "ItemDetails"]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
   <b-list-group>
      <b-list-group-item
         href="#"
         class="flex-column align-items-start"
         v-for="result in post"
         v-bind:key="result.ItemId"
         v-bind:ItemHeading="result.ItemHeading"
         v-bind:ItemSubHeading="result.ItemSubHeading"
         v-bind:ItemDetails="result.ItemDetails"
      >
         <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="mb-1">{{ result.ItemHeading }}</h6>
            <small>{{ result.ItemSubHeading }}</small>
         </div>

         <p class="mb-1">{{ result.ItemDetails }}</p>
      </b-list-group-item>
   </b-list-group>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   props: ["ItemHeading", "ItemSubHeading", "ItemDetails"]
};
</script>
```